# Logic Pro X : Select all the notes above a specific (reference) note

Tags: midi, daw, logic-pro

In Logic Pro X when you are editing in Piano Roll if you need to select all the notes following a specific (reference) note, you can do it by using the key command shift+F and shift+uparrow is used to select the topmost notes.

Is there a key command (or any other way) to select all the notes above a specific (reference) note?

E.g - I want to select all the MIDI notes above C3 of a piano performance.

Comment: Transform Window - Manual… https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/logicpro/lgcp2158341a/mac

Comment: This works but I need something faster than what I use now : click-n-drag to select using pointer tool which is faster than using a transform window.

Comment: Investigate whether you can make those Transforms into saved presets & key command them. I don't use Logic, I use Cubase, where you can do just that.

Comment: No such options